# CSS clearfix doesn't seem to work

Tags: css, clearfix

I'm trying to use `clearfix`  instead of clear both, but it doesn't work  for some reason. I did everything as the tutorials.

What should I do to make it work?

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
  /* .first_div {
       width:50%; 
       height:50%; 
       background-color:red;
       margin: 50px auto;  
       overflow: auto;
     
    }*/
    
    .second_div {
        width:50px; 
        height:50px; 
        background-color:green;
        float: left;
     
     } 
    
    .third_div {
          width:50px; 
        height:50px; 
        background-color:blue;
         
     } 

.clearfix:after { content: "\00A0"; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0;}
.clearfix{ display: inline-block;}
html[xmlns] .clearfix { display: block;}
* html .clearfix{ height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block}
```

```html
 
 <body>
  <div class="clearfix"> 
    <div class="second_div">sfddsf</div>
    <div class="third_div">sfdsfds</div>
 </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can u show us a Fiddle?

Comment: I think there is a copy error in your clearfix CSS. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: sure https://jsfiddle.net/7vfwys43/

Comment: @Seamus I tried the code in your url and didn't work, but If I put  clear both for .third_div  it works

Comment: I'm assuming you want the two elements next to each other. You need to add `float: left` on the `.third_div`. With both at 50x50, `.second_div` is literally sitting on top of `.third_div` and the text is being pushed out of the box. You can see it this modified example where I made the green 50% opacity. You'll see the box looks teal because of the colors blending. https://jsfiddle.net/7vfwys43/1/

Comment: you can use a display:inline-block on the second div..see https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/7vfwys43/2/

Comment: I know how to fix it,  but my question  if I add clear:both it  solve the problem and the red square appear,but nothing changes when I use clearfix  I just asking if clearfix should fix the float as  clear:both does or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearfix works on floated elements by clearing floats after the element. You are supposed to wrap floated elements with it and as a result, those elements wont be removed from the document flow. In your example `third_div` is not floated. It doesn't make much sense to clear float after the element which is not floated. There is nothing to clear there basically. On other hand, if you add `clear: both` property on the `third_div`, you are clearing the floating value before the `third_div` and as a result, its adding back `second-div` to the document flow. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you have two solutions.

### Example 1

If you need to display elements next to each other, you can float them both and wrap them in clearfix `div`.

CSS

```
.second_div {
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    background-color:green;
    float: left;
} 
.third_div {
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    background-color:blue;
    float: left;
}
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="clearfix"> 
    <div class="second_div">Second div</div>
    <div class="third_div">Third div</div>
</div>
```

### Example 2

If you need display them one under the other, then you only have to float and wrap one of them and the other one will automatically position itself below, following document flow.

CSS

```
.second_div {
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    background-color:green;
    float: left;
} 
.third_div {
    width:50px; 
    height:50px; 
    background-color:blue;
}
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="clearfix"> 
    <div class="second_div">Second div</div>
</div>
<div class="third_div">Third div</div>
```